# Is there a Twitter unfollow JavaScript event similiar to the follow event or a way to make it happen?

Tags: javascript, twitter, dom-events

I want to create a custom follow/unfollow button.  When the user presses my follow button I have the standard twitter popup window appear.  Then, when they press the follow button in that window I have the following JavaScript event to change the button on my page:

```
twttr.events.bind('follow', function(event) {
    // change button
});
```

But what do I do if the user clicks the unfollow button in the popup window?  There doesn't seem to be a twitter JavaScript web intents event (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events) for that.

Comment: Yep, there is an event:

    twttr.events.bind('unfollow', function(event) {
        // change button
    });

Comment: Then why is it not documented?

Answer (score 2):

```
twttr.events.bind('unfollow', function(event)
```